# How can I pass the value in oozie workflow action from a another action which is shell script

Tags: oozie-workflow

I have one oozie workflow as mentioned in the code. And I have two questions for the same.

*First*
I need to get the value calculated from the shell script from action - "shellscript" and this calcluated value I need to pass in another workflow action - counter_decision. i.e the value of variable - variable_from_shellscript  in action counter_decision , should be fetched from the shell action.

*Second*
I am calling action1 repeatedly based on counter_decision . I need every time I call it should be like action1, action2 , action3 .... and so on.How can I do this.

```
    <action name="shellscript">
        <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <exec>${myscript}</exec>
            <file>${myscriptPath}${myscript}#${myscript}</file>
            <capture-output />
        </shell>
        <ok to="counter_decision" />
        <error to="KillEmail" />
    </action>



    <decision name="counter_decision">
        <switch>
            <case to="action1">
              ${counter le variable_from_shellscript}
            </case>
            <case to="dummy">
              ${counter gt variable_from_shellscript}
            </case>
            <default to="end"/>
        </switch>
    </decision>


    <action name="action1" cred="hcat,hive2">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>yarn-cluster</master>
            <mode>cluster</mode>
            <name>${appName}</name>
            <property>
                <name>counter</name>
                <value>${counter + 1}</value>
            </property>         
            <class>${main_class}</class>
            <jar>${projectCore}</jar>
            <arg>${projectConfigFile}</arg>
            <arg>0</arg>
            <arg>main</arg>
        </spark>
        <ok to="action2" />
        <error to="KillEmail" />
    </action>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, we can't decide the action name dynamically. Even though you have multiple cases based on count, ultimately you are calling same spark code.
Why can't you pass the counter value directly to spark action and do your switch logic in it?

If is fine for you, you can use below modified code.

```
<action name="shellscript">
<shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <exec>${myscript}</exec>
    <file>${myscriptPath}${myscript}#${myscript}</file>
    <capture-output />
</shell>
<ok to="decision_maker" />
<error to="KillEmail" />
</action>

<action name="decision_maker" cred="hcat,hive2">
<spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
    <master>yarn-cluster</master>
    <mode>cluster</mode>
    <name>${appName}</name>
    <property>
        <name>counter</name>
        <value>${counter + 1}</value>
    </property>         
    <class>${main_class}</class>
    <jar>${projectCore}</jar>
    <arg>${wf:actionData('shellscript')['counter']}</arg>
</spark>
<ok to="action2" />
<error to="KillEmail" />
</action>
```

Also make sure the script returning output in the form of key-value pairs like below.

counter=10